# how to java override class in an API while using EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader, java

I am trying to override a Java class in an API.

I simply do that: I recreate the package structure as in the API and copy there the class (not yet compiled).

As I know the class loader should find the class in the structure before looking in the API.
Is it right?

Unfortunately that doesn't happen: the code readen is always the one in the class of the API.
Why?
May be it is because the ejb  is contained in a EAR file?

The structure is the following:

1) Ejb module that contains :

- 1.1 my code
- 1.2 the interested API
- 1.3 a Class in the same package structure as in the API at 1.2 with the same Class name

2) a Web module that calls my code in EJB module

3) an EAR module that contains everything.

What I am doing wrong? How should I overwrite the API Class, or better make the Classloader force to find my Class before the API one?
Thx!

Comment: I'm confused. All you need is to override some method of a class present in an external package?

Comment: Which API are you trying to override?  One of the standard java classes? If that's the case then remember that in any web container the standard java classes are loaded _before_ your app.

Comment: There is an API in a .jar file.
Inside there is a package: com.package.classes
In this package there are some Classes: I need to modify one, let's say DoSomething.class, because the API is not mantained anymore and his behaviour is wrng.
To do that I make in my project a package com.package.classes and in it I add a DoSomething.java.

Classloader should search the class before in my project, then in another .jar file.
That as I know..

Comment: It is an API of SocialAuth: Facebook changed its rules and to have some functions I need to modify the content of one class (FacebookImpl)